# Does using a transaction for each request slows them down

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a wierd question does using transaction on each request slows my request and is that something noticable ?

```
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    this._context.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: `SaveChanges` already uses a transaction internally. You don't need another one

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that means if i update many to many relationshio and something fails everything in that scope will rollback even if i called savechanges before ?

Comment: Why would you call `SaveChanges` *twice*? A single call will store the changes to all entities. Unless you're using the *anti*pattern of changing a single entity and calling SaveChanges immediatelly? That will dramatically harm performance and prevent the context from acting as a cache and Unit Of Work. The *normal* and scalable way of using a context is to load/add any objects needed, make any changes required to them and only call `SaveChanges` at the end.

Comment: This will store all changes in a single batch inside a transaction, using optimistic concurrency to detect conflicts. No extra transactions are needed and the chance of blocking other requests is reduce by several orders of magnitude. That's *the* scalable way of modifying data, going back to the late 90s - google for `disconnected recordsets`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Well if you are doing many to many you need the id of inserted documents do you would call save changes to get the id of the inserted row. Am I doing something wrong there also :)

Comment: No you don't. The ORM takes care of that. Adding new rows and retrieving the IDs is part for what SaveChanges does. The ORM *knows* which entities/rows/many-to-many entities are new, generates the appropriate INSERT statements and retrieves the IDs

Comment: Now, *pessimistic concurrency* using extra transactions locks records during the entire operation from loading to the final commit, resulting in far more locks and blocking. That's why it's not used when high throughput and concurency is needed and why it's *not* the default option since 2000.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thx i will change my code to try and do what i want without using begin transaction :)

Answer (score -1):

In Entity Framework, the **SaveChanges()** method internally creates a transaction and wraps all INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations under it. **Multiple SaveChanges()** calls, create separate transactions, perform CRUD operations and then commit each transaction

Your code looks good If you have Multiple **SaveChanges** in a Single Transaction.

If you have Multiple **SaveChanges** in a Single Transaction then EF 6 and EF Core allow us to create or use a single transaction with multiple SaveChanges() calls using the following methods:

**DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()**: Creates a new transaction for the underlying database and allows us to commit or roll back changes made to the database using multiple SaveChanges method calls.

**DbContext.Database.UseTransaction()**: Allows us to pass an existing transaction object created out of the scope of a context object. This will allow EF to execute commands within an external transaction object. Alternatively, pass in null to clear the framework's knowledge of that transaction.

Comment: The code isn't good, it's redundant. `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally. Caching doesn't affect transactions either